# why does the subclass have to invoke the no args constructor in the super class?

Tags: java

On the piece of code below, I understand super(t) in the subclass is explicitly invoking a no-args constructor in its superclass (class B). What I seem to be having problems understanding is why does the subclass have to invoke the no-args constructor in the superclass? I can't seem to work out the purpose of this?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       B b = new B(5);

    }
}
class A extends B {
    public A(int t)  {
        super(t);
        System.out.println("A's constructor is invoked");
    }
}

class B  {



    public B(int k)   {
    System.out.println("B's constructor is invoked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just implement a no-args constructor in `B` and make it print something to the screen. You'll notice, that it doesn't get called (in your example).

Answer (score 3):

Super must be instantiated before sub like `parent must exists before child`.

> I understand super(t) in the subclass is explicitly invoking a no-args constructor in its >superclass (class B)

`super(t)` actually `super(5)` will invoke `public B(int k)`.
`super()` try to invoke `public B()` which does not exist.

Note: *compiler provides no-arg constructor if there is no constructor available in the class.*

Comment: so super(t) is actually passing a int value to public B(int k) in class B?

Answer (score 1):

> super(t) in the subclass is explicitly invoking a no-args constructor in its superclass (class B).

No, `super(t)` can be rewritten as `B(t)`. It is invoking the constructor you have shown in the code.

I believe what you are thinking about is

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

i.e If the code did not do `super(t)` the default no-args constructor would be called, However

> If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error

Comment: so super(t) is actually passing a int value to public B(int k) in class B?

Answer (score 1):

Your class `B` does not have a no-args constructor (that would be one without arguments). If it had one, it would be called automatically by the constructors of `A`. But in the example you have to call it manually with `super(t)` in order to specify the argument(s) that should be used.

Comment: It would only be called by the constructors of A that don't explicitly invoke a superclass constructor.

Comment: so super(t) is actually passing a int value to public B(int k) in class B?

Comment: i'm trying to understand the relationship. Why does there have to either be a no args constructor in B or a super(t) in class A. Why does it not work without either of these?